# animated text with javacript and requestAnimationFrame API

Tags: javascript, animation

Am trying to make animated text using javascript without external modules,
here is what i have achieved now:

```js
let i = 0;
function animateText(){
    const textContainer = document.querySelector('#skills');

    let txt = 'I am a web developer';
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(i == txt.length) return;
        
        textContainer.textContent += txt[i];
        i++;
        requestAnimationFrame(animateText);
    }, 100);

}

requestAnimationFrame(animateText);
```

```css
#skills {
    border-right: 4px solid cadetblue;
    padding: .2rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<span id="skills"></span>
```

my code works fine but i would like to make it more dynamic, the **requestAnimationFrame API** does not accept a function with parameters, so the question is how can i make a dynamic version of my code since the text and the element can be changed i want something like this

```
requestAnimationFrame(animateText(el, txt));
```

but this does not work since the animation API take the timestamp as an argument, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

any ideas or suggestions??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your code as written, there's no need for the initial call to `animateText` to be made from a `requestAnimationFrame` callback, since you're not modifying the DOM immediately when you call the function (only later, after a timeout).

That being the case, there's no reason `txt` can't be a parameter rather than a local variable. Note you want `i` defined *inside* the function, and we'll want an inner function we can call to handle the animation:

```js
function animateText(txt) {
    const textContainer = document.querySelector("#skills");
    let i = 0;
    const oneFrame = () => {
        if (i == txt.length) return;
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            textContainer.textContent += txt[i];
            i++;
            setTimeout(oneFrame, 100);
        });
    };
    setTimeout(oneFrame, 100);
}

animateText("I am a web developer");
```

```css
#skills {
    border-right: 4px solid cadetblue;
    padding: .2rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<span id="skills"></span>
```

---

That said, the code's animation length will vary overall, because it's using `setTimeout` with a 100ms timeout between characters, regardless of whether something held the browser up for a second doing something else. Usually with `rAF`, you want to keep the animation time-based, having it catch up as necessary if something kept the browser busy for a moment. Here's an example of that:

```js
function animateText(txt) {
    let i = 0;
    const textContainer = document.querySelector("#skills");
    const start = Date.now();
    const msPerChar = 100; // 100ms per character
    let next = start + msPerChar;
    const oneFrame = () => {
        while (Date.now() > next) {
            textContainer.textContent += txt[i];
            i++;
            next = start + msPerChar * i;
        }
        if (i < txt.length) {
            requestAnimationFrame(oneFrame);
        }
    };
    requestAnimationFrame(oneFrame);
}

animateText("I am a web developer");

// Intentionally block the browser for 500ms after 200ms
setTimeout(() => {
    const stop = Date.now() + 500;
    while (stop > Date.now()) { // <== NEVER ACTUALLY DO THIS
    }
}, 300);
```

```css
#skills {
    border-right: 4px solid cadetblue;
    padding: .2rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<span id="skills"></span>
```

Which you choose is up to you and your goals for the animation.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, this was the answer that i looked for, i was a little bit confused about the way i should use the requestAnimationFrame